# Excel VBA: Application-defined or object-defined error when setting a cell formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new here.

I'm trying to set the formula of a cell to a given string as below, but am getting a run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. The cell is on the active sheet and I can set the formula to blank in the immediate window but I cannot set it to the formula below without hitting the error.

```
Cells(47, i).Formula = "=('sheetName'!$C$105-SUM(OFFSET($C$47,0,0,1," + _
    CStr(i - 3) + ")))/(COLUMN($N$47)-COLUMN(" + _
    CStr(i - 1) + "$47))"
```

I'm wondering if there is some special character restrictions on the string?

Comment: something wrong with this part: `COLUMN(" + CStr(i - 1) + "$47))"` because as I see `CStr(i - 1)` will return number

Comment: Nevermind! Rookie-mistake. I have the second use of CStr above sending in a number as a cell reference. I set it to Col_Letter(CLng(i - 1)) instead and it works just fine. Col_Letter is a function which returns the letter value of the column number given.

Comment: Thanks simoco, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error because of this

`COLUMN(" + CStr(i - 1) + "$47))"`

The cell address has to be like `A1` i.e a `Letter` and then the `Number`.

Comment: just added the same comment:)

Comment: OH I am sorry. I can delete my answer. You can put that as an answer if you want.

Comment: Thanks Siddharth, thanks simoco, that was the problem exactly. I fixed it by using Col_Letter(CLng(i - 1)), which returns the column letter corresponding to the long value given.